# Delete example folder in tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, server, tomcat8

I'm using a tomcat server in production stage project and it's handling high traffic.Now i need to remove example folder under webapp folder.Is it ok? are there any issue, if i remove that folder. I know example folder has no usefullness for the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this in my test servers and It was safely deployed. And i tested this while sending high traffic. But there were no issue.